# Prisma: Update using "where" with non-unique fields?

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

When checking out the typings for the update method in Prisma ORM, I found that I can only include a where clause for unique fields:

```
return this.prisma.publication.update({
    data,
    where: {id},
});
```

I'd love to combine this with authentication and do something like:

```
return this.prisma.publication.update({
    data,
    where: {id, owner: user.id}, <-- Authorisation
});
```

Is this at all possible with Prisma or do I need a separate query for this that retrieves the instance?

Answer (score 12):

In this case, you would need to use [updateMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#update-multiple-records) as you are using a non-unique field along with the unique one.

Comment: Wow that is nasty. So even though you pass unique param and know it will only update one/none record, you need to do a updateMany anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, as of Prisma version 4.5.0, there is a new feature allowing you to add non-unique fields to the unique where clause as long it contains at least one unique field.

[Prisma realese 4.5.0](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/4.5.0)

It's a preview feature so in order to enable it, add this to your shcema.prisma:

```
generator js {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["extendedWhereUnique"]
}
```

And then your code sample will work.

```
return this.prisma.publication.update({
  data,
  where: {id, owner: user.id},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you enable preview feature `extendedWhereUnique`, you will be able to specify non unique properties in the where clause.

Complete documentation is here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#permission-checks

To enable it just update your schema.prisma file to be like this:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["extendedWhereUnique"]
}
```

here the new line added is `previewFeatures = ["extendedWhereUnique"]`

Comment: I was wondering what was happening with the documentation there. It should link instead to why extendedWhereUnique is used, not just that permission checks exist.